# Parsing a text file containing device information

Tags: c#, parsing

After trying a couple of parsers, such as [Log Parser 2.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659), I ended up writing a small utility that supposedly parses the following information onto an object:

(from DirectX Caps Viewer, truncated)

```
DirectX Graphics Adapters
   AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series
         Driver                          aticfx32.dll
         Description                     AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series
         DriverVersion                   524305656590
         VendorId                        4,098
         DeviceId                        26,649
         SubSysId                        -501,147,829
         Revision                        0
         DeviceIdentifier                {D7B71EE2-2B59-11CF-3570-2BC2BEC2C535}
         WHQLLevel                       1
      Display Modes
            640 x 480           D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8                          60
            1920 x 1200         D3DFMT_R5G6B5                              60
      D3D Device Types
         HAL
            Caps
                  DeviceType                                   1
                  MaxPixelShaderValue                          3.40282E+038
               Caps
                     D3DCAPS_READ_SCANLINE                        Yes
               Caps2
                     D3DCAPS2_CANCALIBRATEGAMMA                   No
                     D3DCAPS2_DYNAMICTEXTURES                     Yes
               Caps3
                     D3DCAPS3_ALPHA_FULLSCREEN_FLIP_OR_DISCARD    Yes
               PresentationIntervals
                     D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE                      Yes
                     D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_TWO                      Yes
                     D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_THREE                    Yes
                     D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_FOUR                     Yes
                     D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE                Yes
               CursorCaps
                     D3DCURSORCAPS_COLOR                          Yes
                     D3DCURSORCAPS_LOWRES                         No
            Adapter Formats
               D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8 (Fullscreen)
                  Back Buffer Formats
                     D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8
                        MultiSample Types
                              D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE
                              D3DMULTISAMPLE_2_SAMPLES
```

Here's the code.  It basically uses a regular expression to differentiate whether each line is an entry or a category.  Then, using `list`, it will add that current item to its parent.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"..\..\hd7850all.log")))
        {
            var categories =
                new List<Tuple<int, Category>>(new[] {new Tuple<int, Category>(-1, new Category {Name = "root"})});
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string s = reader.ReadLine();
                if (s == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Input string cannot be null");
                //bool isCategory = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[\w]");
                //bool isSubCategory = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^ +(?!.* {2,})");
                bool isAnyCategory = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^ *(?!.* {2,})");
                bool isEntry = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"(?<!^ *) {2,}");
                int depth = Regex.Match(s, "^ *").Length;
                string name = Regex.Replace(s, "^ *", string.Empty);
                var category = new Category {Name = name};
                var value = new Tuple<int, Category>(depth, category);

                if (isAnyCategory)
                {
                    for (int i = categories.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        Tuple<int, Category> tuple = categories[i];
                        if (tuple.Item1 < depth)
                        {
                            tuple.Item2.Categories.Add(category);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    categories.Add(value);
                }
                else if (isEntry)
                {
                    Tuple<int, Category> tuple = categories.Last();
                    tuple.Item2.Entries.Add(new Entry {Name = name});
                }
            }

            Category root = categories[0].Item2;
        }
    }
}

public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Categories = new List<Category>();
        Entries = new List<Entry>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }

    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public class Entry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Do you know of a more efficient method or approach to transform such data to an object?

Comment: Yes, this question is on-topic.

Comment: Why are you looking for a more efficient approach? Is your code too slow? If it is, what did profiling tell you? What is the slowest part?

Comment: Not really, it does work pretty well though some categories are seen as entries instead. It's more about getting a different point of view. And well, what you see here took me quite some time to get to it as, as usual I started with a complex solution and after many iterations I'm satisfied with it and it's really simple now. In short, I am expecting a review about it !

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of whitespaces in regex patterns threw me off, I think they should be captured with `\s`.

Also your object model doesn't seem to reflect the file's format. I see this:

- `GraphicAdapter`

  - `.Driver` (="aticfx32.dll")
  - `.Description` (="AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series")
  - `.DriverVersion` (="524305656590")
  - `.VendorId` (="4,098")
  - `.DeviceId` (="26,649")
  - `.SubSysId` (="-501,147,829")
  - `.Revision` (="0")
  - `.DeviceIdentifier` (="{D7B71EE2-2B59-11CF-3570-2BC2BEC2C535}")
  - `.WHQLLevel` (="1")
  - `.DisplayModes`
  - `.DeviceTypes`
- `DisplayMode`

  - `.Resolution` (="640 x 480")
  - `.WhateverThatIs` (="D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8")
  - `.RefreshRateHz` (="60")
- `DeviceType`

  - `.Identifier` (="HAL")
  - `.Caps`
  - `.AdapterFormats`

And so on and so forth - what I mean is that there's much more than "entry" and "category" going on here, by merely capturing "entry" and "category" you're missing out on the richness of the data you're parsing.

Comment: While strongly typed access to data (similar to types generated from XML schema, if this was XML) is nice, I think there is a place for a more weak approach too (more akin to plain LINQ to XML).